# How do I change the playlist shuffle?

Tags: youtube-api

Can I change the order of the shuffle? because always plays the same musics. I've about 80 songs that play in the same order every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can not do this** using <kbd>youtube-api</kbd> .
This is actually a **bug**.   And it has been reported already.
[See this](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29).

Comment: Really? Do you know when this was reported?